# Junit Test case for main class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I have a main class like below. How can I write a test case for this?

```
public class Application{

private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

  public static void main(String[] args){
   context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
  }
  public static ConfigurableApplicationContext getContext(){
   return context;
  }

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to write unit test for this class? This is just starting up your spring application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyApplicationTest {
   @Test
   public void main() {
      Application.main(new String[] {});
   }
}
```